# #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, xampp, mariadb-10.4

I got this message when I try to run query on XAMPP in macOS

> #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100421. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error

I tried to write

> 'mysql_upgrade -u root -p'

on my terminal but I got this message

> zsh: command not found: mysql_upgrade

Answer (score 3):

I also could not run the code from the Terminal. I was, however, able to go to the folder itself and "run" the mysql_upgrade application. If you are using XAMPP and the Application Manager, there's a button to Open Application Folder. If you click that, finder will open where XAMPP lives. Open the bin folder. Then scroll until you find mysql_upgrade. Double click it. It will run in a Terminal session and complete the upgrade. Hope this helps someone else as I spent waaayyyy too much time trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into same issue and after cracking my head for the past 10hrs, I finally realize how to perform the upgrade. U

go to your Mac terminal and paste the following code (if you are actually using XAMPP):

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

Supply your root password and see it work like magic.

Contrary to what many people posted online by using /opt/lampp/bin

It always gives a zsh not found error.

I hope this helps you and in the future for others who might need it.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but i still run into zsh not found when i paste the code you suggest in my mac terminal, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @DirgaAdiGuna, Did you try to restart your xampp server. do that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching to a different shell, say bash by typing **bash** in your terminal.
Then proceed to run **mysql_upgrade** normally in the appropriate directory